# Unable to make to directive work for OwlCarousel

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Everything is working in the DOM. Elements are being created. However the plugin fails to render the template. What am I doing wrong? The problem is that I dont know if the plugin is failing or the Angular directive is not working properly?

Please see it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mcw307YxPDtuHXzZVxUO?p=preview
Please right click and inspect the .owl-carousel element during preview mode.

Comment: did my answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you very much! Dastet dard nakone Mohammad. Ali bud!;)

Comment: You're welcome, Khahesh mikonam ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- `scope.$watch` is used for watching isolate scope properties, not attributes, for watching attributes you need to use `attrs.$observe`.
- What is the meaning of passing in the directive template here:

  `<div class="owl-carousel" data="data" options="{items : 4, scrollPerPage : true }" template="'item.html'" ></div>`

You've passed the directive template in the directive definition as the `templateUrl` already.

- When you pass a variable to your directive, and if that variable is something you expect to change frequently and you want your UI bindings updating accordingly, as is the case with the images array here, you should really use an isolate scope instead of an attribute to pass data to the directive. You could use attributes, but with a few gotchas, first you must pass in your attribute to the directive by evaluating it first (using `{{}}`), otherwise it gets passed in to the directive as a string "data":

`<div class="owl-carousel" data="{{data}}"`

NOT:

`<div class="owl-carousel" data="data"`

The latter case would be OK if you passe din `data` through an isolate scope.

[See working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MgnUjPHYSGRbnrJ9YHdy?p=preview).